Few emails are not moving from one folder to another in the shared emailboxes
I am using below code in my automated process to move message from inbox to another folder. But few emails are not getting moved. It is taking 1 - 2 hour, sometimes more than a day or two.
var requestBody = new MovePostRequestBody
{
    DestinationId = "deleteditems",
};

var result = await graphClient.Me.Messages["{message-id}"].Move.PostAsync(requestBody);


A move should be immediate and what you should get returned is the newId of the Item that was moved (unless you using immutable Id's).  How are verifying that email has moved ? a lot of the mail clients are cached (eg outlook cache mode) so it could be the client sync processes that may be conflicting see https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/outlook-365-folder-sync-issues/9739daa3-c0cc-4de1-ad1e-6d9dfe4db852, If your processing new emails that are arriving in a Mailbox adding a small delay sometimes can help to avoid conflicts from multiple clients make changes.
